# Add a single unifying Legend over many plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting several lines in the same figure (which is a football pitch) like so:

```
fig, ax = create_pitch(120, 80,'white')
for index, pass_ in cluster5.iterrows():
    if (index < 0):
        continue
    x, y = pass_['x'], pass_['y']
    end_x, end_y = pass_['end_x'], pass_['end_y']
    y = 80 - y
    end_y = 80 - end_y
    color = color_map[pass_['possession']]
    ax.plot([x, end_x], [y, end_y], linewidth = 3, alpha = 0.75, color = color, label = pass_['possession'])
ax.legend(loc = 'upper left')
```

There are several groups and I would like to plot a single legend for them.
However, I now have a legend of repeated items (one for each call to ax plot for each label).

How can I just plot a single legend item for each label?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a proxy plot and handle:

```
for c in color_labels:
    ax.plot(x, y, linewidth = 3, color = color_map[c], alpha = 0.75, label = c)
```

with `x, y` being the last used one. such that the final color is the same.